# Seeing a pattern (puzzle)

Tags: puzzle

Does someone see a pattern?:

1

11

21

1211

111221

312211

13112221

1113213211

31131211131221

13211311123113112211

111312211331121321113212221

Comment: This is the 'Look and say' sequence: https://oeis.org/A005150

Answer (score 6):

Yes it's called look and say sequence. To generate the next term you have to "say" the digits in the term and write them down accordingly.

For example, first term is $1$. So how many $1$'s ? One $1$. So the next term is $11$, then now say the term, it's two $1$'s, so the next term $21$ and etc.

Answer (score 4):

This is the [look-and-say sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence). You can also find it [on OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C+11%2C+21%2C+1211&language=english&go=Search).